# Modified package.path for loaded lua file

Tags: lua

I'm trying to `loadfile` a script that has extra directories for `require` to search in in.

I have this file structure:

```
.
├── hidden
│  └── a.lua
└── main.lua
```

a.lua:

```lua
return "I was found"
```

main.lua:

```lua
local env = setmetatable(
    { package = setmetatable(
        { path = './hidden/?.lua;' .. package.path }, { __index = _ENV.package })
    }, { __index = _ENV }
) -- Here i'm trying to create a custom `_ENV`, which points to the current `_ENV` except for the package.path variable.

print(load("return package.path", nil, "t", env)()) -- does indeed print './hidden/?.lua;...'
print(load("return require('a')", nil, "t", env)()) -- module 'a' not found
```

Am I misunderstanding how `package.path` works, or is the problem somewhere else?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Try: ```print(load("return require('hidden.a')", nil, "t", env)())``` - The Dot should bring it to work - But dont ask me if it is also Documented somewhere

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi I do not have control over the loaded code. It requires files it assumes are available from `./?.lua` but that is not the case because of the way I organize the files. Sorry for not making this clear in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the Lua source, `require` doesn't look up `_ENV.package`, it uses an upvalue to refer to the "package" table. This means that in your example, `_ENV.package` is no longer the table used internally by `require` and so `_ENV.package.path` is not the `package.path` that is actually used.

One way around it would be to do something like:

```
local oldpath = package.path
package.path = './hidden/?.lua;' .. package.path

print(load("return package.path", nil, "t", env)())
print(load("return require('a')", nil, "t", env)())

package.path = oldpath
```

---

Addendum:

While the Lua `package` library is implemented in C, you could imagine it being implemented in Lua something like this:

```
do
  -- the real default package.path is not a constant,
  -- but it doesn't matter for the mechanism of require.
  local _M = {path = "..."}

  function require(module)

    -- "foo.bar" -> "foo/bar"
    local module_path = module:gsub('%.', '/')

    -- split the pathlist string by ";"
    for subpath in _M.path:gmatch('[^;]+') do

      -- fill in e.g. "./?.lua" with "mymodule" to be "./mymodule.lua"
      local potential_module_path = subpath:gsub('%?', module_path)

      -- try loading the file
      local file = io.open(potential_module_path)
      if file then
          local module_string = file:read('a')
          file:close()
          return load(module_string)()
      end
    end
    error("module '" .. module .. "' not found")
  end

  -- other parts of package.* also elided
  -- the real require also uses package.loaded, package.searchers, package.cpath, etc.
  -- for a more detailed overview, see the Lua reference manual
  
  -- export the "package" module to the global namespace
  package = _M
end
```

So if you re-assign `package` in your code, no matter how you do it, it won't affect `require`, because it uses a particular *table*, not a particular *name*. If you don't re-assign `package`, mutating that table will be seen by `require`.

Comment: Oh is it because the `require` is evaluated when the function returned from `load` is called, not when the `load` itself is called?

Comment: No, the same is true for `return package.path` so that is not the difference. I'll add something to my answer to elaborate.